# sending http requests from docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

I am building a C# console application that sends http requests.

Running the application locally from source, works as expected, the http requests get sent and everything is golden.

Meanwhile when building a container image from the very same source and spinning up an instance from that container locally the http requests frequently time out or return `service temporarily unavailable` errors (503).

I am using `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0` as my base image.

I dont understand how the very same code ran from source code and running inside a docker container have so different behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after posting the question I have found the solution.

I needed to add the following run parameter: `--net host`

I am curious as to why not having this parameter produced this strange behaviour, as sometimes the requests work and sometimes they dont..